# Saving a Dgrid JsonRest-based Store

Tags: rest, dojo, store, dgrid

I have a dgrid that has editable date fields. Above it, I have a "Save" button that calls `grid.save`. When I hit the button, it makes an XHR request back to the store's target, but does not provide any data back to the server for me to save (i.e. POST is empty). Right now it is hardwired to query item id 1900, as you can see in the code below.

Here is how the store is initiated:

```javascript
  var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/safari/resources/1900/calendarObjects/",
    sortParam: "sort",
    idProperty: "id",
    properties: {
        startDate:{
            format: "date-time"
        },
        endDate:{
            format: "date-time"
        }
    }
  });
```

And here is the grid:

```javascript
        var grid = new declare([OnDemandGrid, dgridEditor, Keyboard, Selection, DijitRegistry])({
            store: store,
            query: {responseType: "json" },
            bufferRows: 40,
            loadingMessage: "Loading...",
            columns: [
                {field: "oid", label: "Object ID"},
                dgridEditor({field: "startDate", name: "Start Date", editorArgs: { selector: 'date', datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd', locale: 'en-us' }}, DateTextBox),
                dgridEditor({field: "startTime", name: "Start Time"}, TimeTextBox, "click"),
                dgridEditor({field: "endDate", name: "End Date"}, DateTextBox, "click"),
                dgridEditor({field: "endTime", name: "End Time"}, TimeTextBox, "click"),
                {field: "endDateOid", label: "End OID"}
            ],
        }, "grid");
```

The save button looks like this:

```javascript
registry.byId("saveButton").on("click", function (){
    grid.save();    
 });
```

Like I said, after I click "save," a new XHR request fires, but if it is sending any data back to the server, I'm not sure where it is going. I had my backend print up all of the HTTP headers it received and didn't see anything.

**UPDATE (January 2, 2013):** Upgraded server backend to use a traditional RESTful URL, which seems to make Dojo slightly happier, but it still is using `GET` instead of `PUT` and fails to actually send anything to save.

**UPDATE (January 5, 2013):** Is there any reason why JsonRest would call GET before calling PUT? I'm wondering if my program needs to return certain data before the program is willing to go do the PUT (and thus the problem isn't the GET but whatever comes next)... But, this is entirely speculation. I've reached a dead end.

Comment: I updated the target to be a proper RESTful URL. It requests the appropriate object ID when contacting the server to save changes, but it doesn't actually send the changes and it uses GET rather than PUT.

Comment: The other thing I have noticed is that it always tries to GET id number 1 and not the actual id of the item. I have two id's in my JSON file -- a consecutive one for sorting the table and the unique ones I use to manage items in the database. I would like for Dojo to manipulate the system using the latter, though I have found dgrid was unhappy when I told the system to use those ids since they are not consecutive.

Comment: Someone just edited this post, which reminded me I never found a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the server JSON response from the GET?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will work, you can have a look at https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/JsonRest.html

```
                window.grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, Keyboard]))({
                    store: testStore,
                    getBeforePut: false,
                    columns: columns
                }, "grid");
```

and you can try to set the property `getBeforePut` to `false`.