# Saving dGrid data to JSON file on server

Tags: dojo, dgrid

New to dojo and dGrid, so I hope I'm overlooking something obvious. This is almost same as this [Saving a Dgrid JsonRest-based Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106062/saving-a-dgrid-jsonrest-based-store), which has no accepted answer.

After recently adding an edit box to dGrid (pretty simple), now I'd like to be able to save those changes.  How do I save?  What I tried doesn't work.

```
 define([
'require',
'dgrid/List',
'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
'dgrid/Selection',
'dgrid/Keyboard',
'dgrid/editor',
'dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider',
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/_base/array',
'dojo/Stateful',
'dojo/when',
'dstore/RequestMemory',
'put-selector/put',
'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/domReady!'
 ], function (require, List, OnDemandGrid, Selection, 
    Keyboard, editor, Hider, declare, arrayUtil, Stateful, 
    when, RequestMemory, put, lang) {


storeJunctions = new RequestMemory({ target: require.toUrl('./dataJunctions.json') });

junctionGrid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, editor, Keyboard, Hider]))({
    collection: storeJunctions,
    selectionMode: 'single',
    columns: {
        J1: { label: 'J1', editor: 'text' },
        J2: { label: 'J2', editor: 'text'  },
        ...
    }
}, 'grid');
```

In the HTML I have a save button:

```
<button type='button' onclick="junctionGrid.save();return false;">Save Junctions</button>
```

It couldn't be that simple, so to no surpsie, the data does not post/update to the file on my local dev server.

Comment: What exactly does your server expect back?  PS: the `RequestMemory` store does not perform any server requests beyond the initial request for all data; `add`, `put`, and `remove` all happen strictly in the client-side memory store behind it.

Comment: Ken, on a high level the server expects updated values...  I guess I'm confusing dojo with something like node.js which integrates with server side functionality.  In the meantime, I've created a simple GET url to call from the browser (using .asmx) telling the server to update the file.  Is there a standard practice of creating code on the local server that connects to dojo on the client?  My local server is Django and I could also created a .Net service.